# What are the moments of the value of a random walk stopped at a one-sided hitting time?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, martingales, random-walk, stopping-times

Let $\xi_i$ be i.i.d $L^2(\mathbb{P})$ random variables in a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$, with $\mathbb{E}[\xi_1] = 0, \mathbb{E}[\xi_1^2]=1$, and let $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \xi_i$.

Define the one-sided hitting time $\tau:$
$$\tau := \inf \{ k \geq 0 : S_k < 0 \}.$$
My question is: can we find an expression for $\mathbb{E}[S_\tau]$ and $\mathbb{E}[S_\tau^2]$ and/or determine when these are finite?

I am aware of expressions which make use of optional stopping under some assumptions on the distribution of $\tau$; for example, if  $T$ is a two-sided hitting time, since $(S_{n \wedge T})$ is a bounded martingale, we have $\mathbb{E}[S_T] = 0$ and $\mathbb{E}[S_T^2] = \mathbb{E}[T]$.

My issue is that many of these common analysis tools don't seem to work; since $\tau$ is only one-sided, $\mathbb{E}[\tau] = \infty$ which violates a finite expectation assumption made by many of these tools.

In the case of the simple symmetric random walk, for example, where $\mathbb{P}(\xi_1 = -1) = \mathbb{P}(\xi_1 = 1) = 1/2$, it is quite immediate that $\mathbb{E}[S_\tau] = -1$ and $\mathbb{E}[S_\tau^2] = 1$. This exploits the discrete state space for $(S_n)$. But can anything be said more generally? I am particularly intrested in the case where $\xi_1 \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

Comment: I would be surprised if there was a general statement beyond bounding the magnitude by starting at $0$ and conditioning on a downward step: for $N(0,1)$ this would give you $E[S_T] \ge -\sqrt{\frac2\pi}\approx -0.798$ and  $E[S_T^2] \le 1$.   A quick unchecked simulation suggests $N(0,1)$ could give values closer to $E[S_T]\approx -0.71$ and $E[S_T^2] \approx 0.83$.